# Accessing attribute via reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0, attributes

So I'm trying to access data from a custom attribute in C# using reflection what I have is this:

attribute class:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class Table : System.Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Table (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

I have a separate assembly with the following:

```
[Table("Data")]
public class Data
{
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public enum BankType { City, State, Federal };
}
```

In the main program I enumerate all the files in the current directory, and filter all the dll files. Once I have the dll files I run:

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
var asmTypes = asm.GetTypes();
```

From here I try and load the Table attribute using the Assembly method: `GetCustomAtteribute(Type t, bool inherit)`

However the Table attribute doesn't show in any of the dll, nor does it show as any of the types loaded in the assembly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is the code that goes over the types and tries to pull the attribute:

```
foreach (var dll in dlls)
            {
                var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
                var asmTypes = asm.GetTypes();
                foreach (var type in asmTypes)
                {
                    Table.Table[] attributes = (Table.Table[])type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Table.Table), true);

                    foreach (Table.Table attribute in attributes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(((Table.Table) attribute).Name);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Show your exact code that enumerates the types. I bet you're referencing the wrong `Table` class in a `typeof`...

Comment: You left the most important part of your code, the one where you're loading the attributes using GetCustomAttribute.

Comment: On each item in `asmTypes` you must call `GetCustomAttributes`.

Comment: Also it is unclear what "load the Table attribute" means in relation to using `GetCustomAttribute` which gets list of attributes applied to an entity...

Comment: In your attribute class `Table`, make the setter for `Name` private because otherwise it can be set twice when applying the attribute, so use `public string Name { get; private set; }`.

Comment: Table is a namespace in a separate assembly, and Table is the name of the attribute class, as stated above.

Comment: After your edit: All looks correct to me. Are you sure you have compiled the assembly after applying the attribute, and you are using the new DLL file from that compilation?

Comment: The compilation process it taken care of with the build order, so all assemblies are compiled before being used. The main application has a reference to the attribute assembly in order to use the type. The Data class has a reference to table to be able to use it as a attribute. The attribute is in a separate assembly. Both the attribute and the data assembly get loaded in the dlls IEnumerable<string> object as a path to the file and subsequently get loaded as an assembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Table.Table` is in a separate assembly that both assemblies reference (i.e. there is only one `Table.Table` type), then that *should* work. However, the issue suggests that something is amiss. I recommend doing something like:

```
    foreach (var attrib in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type))
    {
        if (attrib.GetType().Name == "Table")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(attrib.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
```

and putting a breakpoint on the `Console.WriteLine`, so you can see what is happening. In particular, look at:

```
bool isSameType = attrib.GetType() == typeof(Table.Table);
bool isSameAssembly = attrib.GetType().Assembly == typeof(Table.Table).Assembly;
```

Incidentally, I ***strongly*** recommend calling that `TableAttribute`.

Comment: this gives me the Table attribute, finally, I should be able to work on from here. Thanks for your help. P.S. This works so nice I wish I could +1 your answer, several times. Thanks again.

Comment: This isn't very safe, .NET already has a [Table] [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx).  So your last paragraph is actually bad advice :)

Comment: @Hans it will at least allow them to find the type to start identifying what the problem is, hence my `isSameType` and `isSameAssembly` tests; besides, my "last paragraph" is about calling it `TableAttribute` (depending on whether you'd call that a "paragraph" or not) - I maintain that naming it `TableAttribute` is perfectly appropriate, and much better than calling it `Table`